# Integration by parts for Matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I understand how to do integration by parts for individual functions. I am trying to apply integration by parts to matrices/vectors where the order of terms is important. So say I have a matrix A which is n x n and I have two vectors
$\phi$ and $\phi^*$ which are n x 1 and 1 x n respectively. Both the matix and vectors are functions of y. If I want to solve the integral 
\begin{equation*}\int_0^\infty \phi^*A\phi^"dy\end{equation*}
does it simply become 
\begin{equation*}
\phi^*A\phi']_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty(\phi^*A)'\phi'dy
\end{equation*}
or is it something like 
\begin{equation*}
\phi^*A\phi']_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty \phi'(\phi^*A)'dy
\end{equation*}

Comment: Hint: Fundamental theorem of calculus applies to matrices as well. The derivative of a product is $(AB)'=A'B+BA'$. From these you should be able to deduce an integration by parts formula for matrices just like for usual functions.

Comment: ...where I of course should have written $AB'$ instead of $BA'$. Noticing a crucial typo 6 minutes after posting is great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: It helps to remember how one writes out the matrix multiplication in elements, i.e. as $$\phi^* A \phi''=\sum_{jk}\phi_j^* A_{jk}\phi''_k$$
At this stage you've just got a sum of scalar functions and you can integrate them by parts in the usual way; once that's done, figure out what matrix multiplication this represents.